# Корректный ответ на вопрос Python NLP

Tags: python, nlp

Сделал Вопросно-Ответную систему с помощью DeepPavlov [*тык*](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/squad.html)
Далее ввожу текст с технической темой, модель отвечает адекватно на вопрос по этому тексту, однако если я введу вопрос не связанный с этим текстом(Ну например текст про историю возникновения языка python, а вопрос 'Что такое фотосинтез?') выводится полный пред. Можно ли это как то предотвратить/обработать? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы модель умела отвечать на любые вопросы?))

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Как я предполагаю, ОП хочет получать на выходе уровень уверенности в ответе, и если он низкий, то выдавать ответ-заглушку.

Comment: @AivanF. именно